# log4j.xml file placement

Tags: logging, log4j

i have created a log4j util class where i'm picking up the file using

```
org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
```

but when testing, it throws

```
log4j:ERROR Could not open [log4j.xml].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.xml (The system cannot find the file specified.)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:72)
```

Can anyone tell me where do i place the log4j.xml file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it on the classpath, in the root folder.

Comment: u mean in the src folder..i have tried that...its nt working

Comment: Search where does the build place the .class files. At the root of that folder log4j.xml should be placed, too.

Comment: ya..got it...i should have put it to root instead of src folder..thanks