# Log4j cannot find properties file in a simple application

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, logging

I have a very simple application that illustrates the function of logging. I use log4j. But I have some trouble with the settings. I downloaded the file **log4j-1.2.16.jar**. And connect it to my project by **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...**. Here are my class:

```
package ru.log4j.log4jhelloworld;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello World!");        
    }
}
```

My **log4j.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="aa %p %c: %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>    
  <!--Root logger-->
  <root>
    <priority value ="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And my **log4j.properties**:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern= %p %c: %m%n
```

In the console displays these exceptions:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ru.log4j.log4jhelloworld.MyClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I do not know how I was supposed to create and connect other supporting files, such as **log4j.xml** and **log4j.properties**. And be sure whether they need? In what directory they should be located? What should I still register? Here is my project structure

[image: screen]
.

I'm guessing that the error in this. What is my problem? Help me please!

Comment: Try placing the properties file / xml file in the root directory instead of placing it within the package ru.log4j.log4jhelloworld. I am also new to log 4j , but by looking at your xml and properties , I feel one of them is good enough , so you can remove one and try

Comment: possible duplicate of [log4j.xml file placement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012572/log4j-xml-file-placement)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve your issue place your your log4j configuration file(i.e. `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties`) in the `src` folder and it should work fine.

Moreover you don't need both files(`log4j.xml` and `log4j.properties`), just use one of them.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the logger system cannot find your config file. To fix it you have several options:

1. If you need to keep logger config outside of your packaged classes (which you usually do in real production system) then

   - put your logger config file somewhere on file system outside of your classpath (e.g. `/etc/my_great_app/log4j.xml` )
   - Include path to your config in your Java application command line, like this 

     `-Dlog4j.configuration=<path log4j config>`

     e.g.

     `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/my_great_app/log4j.xml`

     Note that path must include prefix `file://`.
2. If you'd like to keep your log4j configuration along with your code (which is typical for unit tests), then all you need to do - just make sure that log4 config location is part of the classpath. For example if you're using maven, just store your `log4j.properties` in `src/main/resources` directory

Regarding difference between `log4j.properties` vs `log4j.xml`. They are just 2 different ways to define same configuration for log4j logger. You don't need both files, just decide what format you like more and use it :)

Answer (score 2):

> log4j.properties file put in src folder file like bellow

```
com.org.slk.LogExample.java
com.org.slk.log4j.properties
```

> and then set   PropertyConfigurator  in LogExample.java

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(LogExample.class.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));
```

> and property file set configuration like bellow log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File= fullpath /myLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the application with the -Dlog4j.debug VM argument and you will be prompted with the place where log4j want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. And solved it by putting the following lines in Run AS--> Run Configurations --> Arguments tab

`-Dcvp.property.path=/home/local/Project/property/`  --> location of your property file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your `log4j.properties` file any location in your project.
And then load your file

```
private static Logger logger = null;

static {
    System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "C:\\Users\\jhaas\\Workspace_3.0.30\\RestClient\\conf\\log4j.properties");
}
```

It is similar to set the VM argument in eclipse like

`-Dlog4j.configurationFile= "C:\\Users\\jhaas\\Workspace_3.0.30\\RestClient\\src\\main\\resources\\log4j.properties"`

Better approach is to have it in your code rather than setting into the eclipse VM argument.

Comment: static code initializer need to run before any use of the logger. This might be problematic. The VM argument is safier at my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` files should be under root source folder `src/main/resources`.

Create new source folder `src/main/resources` and place the `property` or `xml` file there. It should solve the problem