# where to put config.properties and log4j.xml in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, classpath, configuration-files

When I first developed my Java app, I ended up with my config.properties and log4j.xml files in the 'src' directory.  This worked fine running in Eclipse, but now I am trying to deploy to a Linux server.

When I deploy, I take the exported app jar file and explode it, but it of course does not have the 'src' directory.

When I move the two config files back to the root of the app, log4j is complaining that it cannot find the log4j.xml file.

I have tried to set the Run/Debug classpath as noted in several posts, but the Classpath tab already appears to show the app's main directory there.

What I need is to understand how I should lay out things like these two configuration files in Eclipse, so that when I export to a jar for deployment they are still visible.

Thanks,

Mitch

Comment: Did you try src/main/resources ?

Comment: If you created your java app from Eclipse then your files placed at "src" folder should be exported inside the jar file. Check your project configuration files, the is a tab named "Build" in which you can select which files are included in your jar and which of them are not.

Comment: It is true that the files get placed inside the jar file, but my Spring applicationContext.xml file has the log4j.xml file in 'src/log4j.xml'.  Clearly, when I deploy on another machine, the 'src' file doesn't get copied over.   

So my real problem is to make sure that the code, both mine and Spring, work the same in Eclipse and on Linux as far as where they look for the config.properties file and log4j.xml.

How can I set the "arguments" list for the log4jInitialization entry in applicationContext.xml so that it looks for log4j.xml in the base directory of the application?

Comment: ok, I added an answer that may help you to find the way of configuring the location of a log4j.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Place the log4j.xml on src/main/resources in eclipse. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a line.

```
 Log4jConfigurer.initLogging("SpringTest/src/log4JTest/log4j.xml");
```

to inform **log4J** that from here it should pick all custom info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have placed your `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file in your `src` folder then it should work fine for the exported jar file as well. You could have a look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9305535/948268) which is similar.

Answer (score 0):

maybe configuring it as "classpath:log4j.xml" in your applicationContext.xml is enough, or, if it is not what you really want I suggest you to take a look about how to set it up using the approach of a [`Log4jDirectConfigurer`](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?37896-log4j-configuration-in-applicationContext).